# In Prolog should one avoid to use the ";" operator?

Tags: prolog, coding-style

When writing Prolog predicates with multiple choice points (equivalent to an if-then-else or a case-statement) is it better to write several different predicates with the same signature, separated by a `.` or rather to write all the case in one big predicate in which the different cases are separated by a `;`? Is one more efficient than the other (for example because the predicates are shorter and can be indexed for faster access)? Or is it just a good convention to use one or the other? For readability I would sometimes prefer shorter predicates and avoid `;` (except if it would lead to too much code duplication.) But I observed that students writing code tend to go for the longer predicates with a lot of `;`.

Here's an example of student code from a project where they were asked to simulate implementing an SQL-like language in Prolog. (The `drop/1` predicate corresponds to the drop command in SQL. If the table doesn't exist it throws an error. Otherwise it deletes the table name from the list of known tables and deletes all rows in that table with the `delete/1` predicate.)

```
drop(Table) :-
    \+ table(Table, _), throw("No such table");
   delete(Table), retract(table(Table, _)).
```

Other students wrote this in two separate rules as follows:

```
drop(Table) :-
    \+ table(Table, _), !, throw("No such table").

drop(Table) :-
    table(Table, _), delete(Table), retract(table(Table, _)).
```

Comment: I mostly prefer `;` , so that it can be easily changed during development to be using `->` or `*->`. Also, it's a bit easier to debug, as opposed to head unification failing. I don't think performance is a significant factor. Taking advantage of first-argument indexing can be a factor.

Comment: Thanks @brebs for your answer. I can see why it is easier to adapt and perhaps to debug. What about the readability of such long predicates with `;`? (But it is true that with `->` I would prefer all in a same rule so your argument makes sense.

Comment: It really depends on the use case. As a rule of thumb, if you _can_ use syntactical unification in the head, you _should_. Sometimes you can also use two separate clauses and a cut instead of a `->`. I would say that this is a misplaced questions, in the sense that "it depends", as it always does :-) What could be answered, though: give a concrete example and ask "what are the benefits and drawbacks of using `;` or trying to avoid it?"

Comment: If the code twists and turns enough for readability to be an issue, then sure, split into multiple predicates. Coding is an art :-)

Comment: @brebs Art is usually useless, and beauty is in the eye of the beholder etc. So yes, coding on Stackoverflow is indeed an art; but I at least do my best to avoid art when coding at work ;-)

Comment: In the freshly-added example - calling `tabl/2` *twice* is easily avoidable.

Comment: What are the semantics of this? What does delete/1 do? With this incomplete snippet, I'd say that a single `retractall(tabl(Table,_))` would do the trick. You should provide a reproducible example..... The `throw(format....)` esp is very sus. And choice points, so many of them.....

Comment: I adapted and explained the example better. The purpose of the example is not that important.

Comment: Surely you have a more interesting example than that?

Comment: You do realize the two version have different semantics, I hope? Like, they will behave differently (how _exactly_ they will behave, we cannot tell, because you still have not provided a reproducible example....)

Comment: The two examples come from two different students and I wanted to show the difference in style. I cannot show the entire code because (1) it would be too long, (2) I don't want to give away the entire solution for new generations of students. But I think I have my answer now and thank you both for the very interesting interaction we had on this.

Answer (score 0):

I will take your last comment and try address it here, even though the Q/A format is not meant for that kind of discussion. Your question itself is a bad fit for this site but we are already here so anyway....

You say, in addition to the question which I don't need to quote,

> I adapted and explained the example better. The purpose of the example is not that important.

The only relevant thing is the purpose of the code. Your code has a purpose; based on that purpose you can try to formulate your intentions using building blocks (predicates, functions, procedures, modules, whatev) with defined semantics and hopefully run-time characteristics (big O, memory etc). Only then you can start thinking how to program this in a way that fulfils the original purpose **and** is still "idiomatic" or "clean" or whatever you call the thing that makes the code useful to other programmers.

Which is why I said above, "it depends". Hopefully I managed to explain a bit better what depends on what. Sorry for the long-winded answer.